# Sequence classification Tensorflow - LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, sequence

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
id.   date           mycol       label

1.    01/12/2019      c1             1
1.    03/12/2019      c2             1
1.    04/12/2019      c3             1
2.    01/12/2019      c1             0
2.    03/12/2019      c5             0 
3.    15/01/2020       ..            1
4.     ...                           1
.
.
```

Label is always the same for the same id and it is a binary classification problem. I would like to predict label based on mycol only for each id and I need to make predictions 5 months in advance. I think I should be using LSTM's but the problem is in the dates and how to set up the sequences since I haven't seen this kind of problem before and I am just starting with LSTM's. Grouping by id gives very large lists of mycol values for every row. I am not sure how to distinguish those values in terms of months/weeks and if I should do that at all or should I just leave them like that in a 1 huge list for every row. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you should approach the problem as a time series problem. Yes, LSTM can solve it but try to use a simpler model like ARIMA or some variation of ARIMA

Comment: Do you have any examples of how this might work?

Answer (score 0):

Your first input sequence should be [c1, c2, c3], label - 1,

the second - [c1, c5], label - 0,

...

Sequence length doesn't matter (you don't have to add padding). LSTM learns how to change its state weights based on new input (sequence element).

Comment: Your initial question is classification task: you have a sequence as input and label  as output. Please clarify - how are you going to predict 6 months in advance: do you want to predict mycol rather than label ? If so - you have to train another LSTM to predict mycol for 6 months and then feed the predicted sequence to the first LSTM for classification.

Comment: If your label affects mycol - it could be more efficient to train one LSTM for the both purposes (because LSTM has two outputs). You need to use loss comprising of two losses (separate loss for every purpose)

Comment: I have no code example. You should use BinaryCrossentropy for sequence classification and SparseCategoricalEntropy for next element prediction